# Enable saving core in Impala

Tags: java, impala

I am having a very hard time figuring out how to save impala cores. I am trying to run some queries with UDFs and they are failing. In the impala log, all I see is the message like this:

> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try `ulimit -c unlimited` before starting Java again

I tried running `ulimit -c unlimited` and then restarted impala service. However, it does not save the core. Anyone had similar issues and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On clusters managed by Cloudera Manager, go to the Impala service, then under the "Configuration" tab search for "Enable Core Dump" and check the box.  Then restart Impala.

For unmanaged clusters, the document https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_config_options.html#config_options_noncm states:

> Core dump enablement. To enable core dumps on systems not managed by Cloudera Manager, change:
>
> ```
> export ENABLE_CORE_DUMPS=${ENABLE_COREDUMPS:-false}
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> export ENABLE_CORE_DUMPS=${ENABLE_COREDUMPS:-true}
> ```

This is done in the defaults file `/etc/default/impala`.  Then restart the Impala services you are interested in.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_config_options.html
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IMPALA/Impala+Debugging+Tips